# Problem exporting a large classified image in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, geotiff-tiff, export, land-classification, image-classification

I am trying to export a GeoTIFF image but it doesn't work. https://code.earthengine.google.com/fe534ace7f3fc4fdfd155ded24155525

When I export the large classified image to Google Drive, I don't get an error and the task takes a long time and finally, I can't see the GeoTIFF image.

Here is the export request:

```
 Export.image.toDrive(
                {image:PBS_OUT.float(),    //'B2','B3','B4',
                description: 'PBS_S2_2019',
                fileNamePrefix:'PBS_S2_2019',
                 folder: '', 
                 region:AOI.geometry().bounds(),
                 scale:20, //10
                 skipEmptyTiles:true,
                 maxPixels: 1e13
                });
```

Any ideas for getting my export task to be successful?

Comment: This is a common issue because your study area is too big and fairly complicated (110456 vertices). I think you should draw less complicated sub-areas from your main area, then export each of them separately.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't see the GeoTIFF image"? Does it download to Google Drive? If it does, how are you viewing it? I see that you are exporting it as a float type image. These data types will generally not render in software intended for 8-bit RGB(A) images. If you are viewing it in a GIS, then you will likely need to set the visualization properties to the appropriate band min and max values for the expected valid data range. If it is classified data (integer), the float type is probably not what you want - generally `byte()` or `short()` would be best.

Comment: The image is never downloaded to Google Drive. Task details state: running on server but it takes up to 10 hours then I have to cancel because I suposse it is not normal. To clarify, The image contains classified data. In the beginning, I was exporting as byte() then I have changed to float() because I thought it could improve the time to download but it doesn't.